# Spatial Arrangement of Permutational Probability

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

I have 4 black balls and 4 red balls, I need to fill 8 baskets with one ball each. How many different arrangements can I have such that each arrangement is unique. So if black balls are represented as 0 and red as 1, the arrangements 1110001 and 1000111 are two unique arrangements.

Please let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can distribute the black balls in $\binom{8}{4}$ ways, the red balls are fixed then. So, the answer is $70$.